# How to export/import NetBeans settings (like theme, editor colours etc.)?

Tags: netbeans, intellij-idea, configuration

IntelliJ IDEA (as of version 14.0.2) has an option to export/import user preferences with menu options 'File->Export Settings...' and 'File->Import Settings'. I wonder what is the simplest way to achieve a similar effect in NetBeans 8.0.2?

Note: I want to store my NetBeans IDE settings under version control on GitHub so that I can readily import them whenever I need (e.g. after OS reinstalls).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Tools | Options has an import/export.

Comment: **Tools | Options** menu is not present in my default Netbeans 8.0.2 installation.

Comment: I managed to enter this menu with `Command-,` shortcut on OS X.

Answer (score 2):

For those who may be trying to access the Options menu on a Mac, it's available under `Netbeans->Preferences` (or `command + ,`).  The export and import options are on the General tab in the lower left corner.

Answer (score 1):

To be precise if not sufficently clear reading the answers:

On netbeans 12.0, and previous versions ->

Tools -> Options -> Editor
Select Import Button
Then select the version of Netbeans to import from
Select the settings to overwrite
Confirm

The IDE will restart...